# stdin allows to read with the EOF flag set

Tags: c, stdin, eof, standard-library

On my platform, the following code allows me to successfully read from `stdin` even if its end-of-file flag is set, which also remains set after the read. To reproduce the behavior, first type the end-of-file shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Unix, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows) and then type a normal character.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// first type the shortcut for EOF, then a single character

int main(void) {
    getchar();
    printf("feof(stdin): %s\n", feof(stdin) ? "true" : "false");
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF) return 0;
    printf("%c\n", (char) ch);
    printf("feof(stdin): %s\n", feof(stdin) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

The output I get (after typing the letter `f`):

```
feof(stdin): true
f
feof(stdin): true
```

From C11 standard (7.21.7.1, *The `fgetc` function*, 3):

> **Returns**
>
> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`

`getchar()` is equivalent to `getc(stdin)` (7.21.7.6), which in turn is a macro for `fgetc(stdin)` (7.21.7.5). So `getchar()` should behave exactly like `fgetc(stdin)`.

It seems to me that this is is not standard compliant. Am I missing something?

---

This question previously referred to C++ (thus the long discussion in comments), but the problem can be narrowed to the C standard library, thus I edited. Still the following information may be relevant:

The behavior is not consistent among platforms:

- Arch Linux, GCC 7.3.1: *can* read after EOF;
- Windows 7, GCC (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0: *can* read after EOF;
- MacOS High Sierra, Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2): *cannot* read after EOF;
- FreeBSD 10.3, both clang 3.4.1 and GCC 5.4.0: *cannot* read after EOF.

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49880746/1202636), which is about the fact the `cin.clear()` does not seem to unset the end-of-file flag of `stdin`, after some useful comments and chat discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux this is indeed a known `glibc` bug in stdio implementation: [#1190 - from 2005](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190), [#19476 - duplicate from 2016](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19476) which got fixed only in recent 2.28 build.